# In Python, replace string in another string using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string "N.320" (N+dot+<number>) and I need to replace for "NR 320" for example.

I tried this command: `x = re.sub((r"N'+'\.''"), 'NR ', 'RUA SAO VICENTE DE PAULA N.320')`.

This does not work as expected. How can I do that?

Comment: @Cœur Thanks for giving me feedback. I will take it improve my next edits!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `(r"N'+'.''")`, just use `N.`, you dont need the `+`. Use positive lookahead `(?=\d)` to make sure you only match when `N.` is followed by a digit and not just somewhere in the middle of string.

```
x = re.sub(r"N.(?=\d)", 'NR ', 'RUA SAO VICENTE DE PAULA N.320')
```

> RUA SAO VICENR E DE PAULA NR 320

Comment: It works, tank you, and sorry about so simple doubt... Tank you very much

Comment: The dot have to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
x = ' '.join(re.sub("N.", "NR ", txt).split())
```